# How to send into modal 4 different values for input radio with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a sales script and my client need a modal with 4 prices per product within in a input radio. I have tried in several ways, but I can not understand how to send the 4 prices to a radio input within modal for each line of product.

Every line of product is added by javascript, like this:

```
var addNewRow = function(id){
    html = '<tr id="tr_'+i+'">';
    html += '<td class="prod_c" width="50%"><input type="text" data-type="nombreProd" name="nombreProd[]" id="nombreProd_'+i+'" class="form-control autocomplete_txt" autocomplete="off"></td>';
    html += '<td width="10%"><input type="text" name="cantidad[]" id="cantidad_'+i+'" class="form-control changesNo cq totalCantidad" autocomplete="off" onkeypress="return IsNumeric(event);" ondrop="return false;" onpaste="return false;"></td>';
    html += '<td width="10%"><input type="text" name="venta[]" id="venta_'+i+'" class="form-control changesNo vventa" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#escoger" autocomplete="off" onkeypress="return IsNumeric(event);" ondrop="return false;" onpaste="return false;" readonly="readonly"></td>';
    html += '<td width="25%"><input type="text" name="total[]" id="total_'+i+'" class="form-control totalLinePrice pisto" autocomplete="off" onkeypress="return IsNumeric(event);" ondrop="return false;" onpaste="return false;" ></td>';
    html += '<td class="trash_td"><i class="fa fa-trash fa-delete" aria-hidden="true" data-id="'+i+'"></i></td>';
    html += '</tr>';

    if( typeof id !== "undefined"){
        $('#tr_'+id).after(html);
    }else{
        $('table').append(html);
    }

    $('#caseNo_'+i).focus();
    i++;

    return (i-1);
};
```

Here is the part where the javascript call the DB to add in every input the data from the product selected:

```
$(document).on('focus','.autocomplete_txt',function(){
    type = $(this).data('type');
id_arr = $(this).attr('id');
id = id_arr.split("_");
element_id = id[id.length-1];
autoTypeNo =1;
if(type =='cod' ){
    autoTypeNo=0;
    $('#add_icon_'+element_id).removeClass('hide');
} else if(type =='nombreProd' ) {
    autoTypeNo=1;
}

$(this).autocomplete({
    source: function( request, response ) {
        $.ajax({
            url : 'partes/include/aPos.php',
            dataType: "json",
            method: 'post',
            data: {
               name_startsWith: request.term,
               type: type
            },
            beforeSend: function(){
                $('#msg').html('<img src="images/ajax-loader.gif"/> <span class="label label-primary">verificando</span>');
            },
            success: function( data ) {
                $('#msgCod').html("");
                if(!data.length && readonly != 'readonly'){

                    $('#product_code_modal').val( $('#itemNo_'+element_id).val() );
                    $('#product_name_modal').val( $('#itemName_'+element_id).val());

                    $('#current_element_id').val(element_id);

                    //$('#add_product_form').find('.form-group').removeClass('animated fadeIn').addClass('animated fadeIn');
                    //$('#addNewProduct').modal('show');

                    /*var result = [
                      {
                          label: 'No record found',
                          value: ''
                      }
                    ];
                    response(result);*/
                }else{
                     response( $.map( data, function( item ) {
                        var code = item.split("|");
                        return {
                            label: code[autoTypeNo],
                            value: code[autoTypeNo],
                            data : item
                        };
                    }));
                }
            }
        });
    },
    autoFocus: true,
    selectFirst: true,
    minLength: 2,
    open: function(e, ui){
        var first = $(".ui-menu-item:eq(0) div").html();
        //$(this).val(first);
        console.log(first);

        return false;
    },
    select: function( event, ui ) {
        if( typeof ui.item.data !== "undefined" ){
            var names = ui.item.data.split("|");
            if( type == 'general'){
                var currentTextid = $('#reciboPos tr:last').find("td.prod_c > input").attr('id');

                if(typeof currentTextid !== 'undefined') {
                    var currentTextArr = currentTextid.split("_");
                    element_id = currentTextArr[currentTextArr.length-1];

                    var cod = $.trim( $("#"+currentTextid).val() );

                    element_id = parseInt(element_id);
                    if (cod !=='') {
                        element_id = addNewRow();
                    }
                } else {
                    element_id = addNewRow();
                }

            }
        $('#nombreProd_'+element_id).val(names[1]);
        $('#cantidad_'+element_id).val(1);
        $('#venta_'+element_id).val(names[2]);
        $('#total_'+element_id).val(names[2]);
 // Here I added thee others three values for each product
        $('#venta1_'+element_id).val(names[3]);
        $('#venta2_'+element_id).val(names[4]);
        $('#venta3_'+element_id).val(names[5]);
            setTimeout(function(){
                $("#autocomplete_top").val("");
                },100);
            }else{
                return false;
            }
            calculateTotal();
        }
    });
});
```

When the product is showed I clicked into the input "venta" to show the modal

```
//modal to choose the price
$('#escoger').on('show.bs.modal', function(e) {

    var venta = $('#venta_0'+id[1]).val();
    var venta1 = $('#venta_1'+id[1]).val();
    var venta2 = $('#venta_2'+id[1]).val();
    var venta3 = $('#venta_3'+id[1]).val();

  $('input[name="venta"][value="'+venta+'"]').prop('checked',true);
  $('input[name="venta"][value="'+venta1+'"]').prop('checked',false);
  $('input[name="venta"][value="'+venta2+'"]').prop('checked',false);
  $('input[name="venta"][value="'+venta3+'"]').prop('checked',false);
});
```

This is the modal, but I don't know how to send the data into each input radio:

```
<div id="escoger" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog">

    <!-- Modal content-->
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">

        <label class="radio-inline mr10">
            <input type="radio" name="venta" id="venta_0">1
        </label>
        <label class="radio-inline mr10">
            <input type="radio" name="venta" id="venta_1">2
        </label>
        <label class="radio-inline mr10">
            <input type="radio" name="venta" id="venta_2">3
        </label>
        <label class="radio-inline mr10">
            <input type="radio" name="venta" id="venta_3">4
        </label>

      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

-----EDIT------

Here the video link with the issue:
[video](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dtmrT.jpg)

Here the another part of script:

```
//price change

$(document).on('change keyup blur','.changesNo',function(){

// .changeNo are the class inside of ventas, cantidad(quantity) inputs

// in this part the ID came from

    id_arr = $(this).attr('id');  
    id = id_arr.split("_");

    cantidad = $('#cantidad_'+id[1]).val();
    existencia = $('#existencia_'+id[1]).val();
    venta = $('#venta_'+id[1]).val();
    venta1 = $('#venta1_'+id[1]).val();
    venta2 = $('#venta2_'+id[1]).val();
    venta3 = $('#venta3_'+id[1]).val();

    if( cantidad!='' && venta!='')

    calculateTotal();

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this is what are you looking for. Do something like below.

JAVASCRIPT

```
$('#escoger').on('shown.bs.modal', function () {

    var venta0 = Math.floor((Math.random() * 100)); // Test value (random). Change it back according to your code later.
    var venta1 = Math.floor((Math.random() * 100)); // Test value (random). Change it back according to your code later.
    var venta2 = Math.floor((Math.random() * 100)); // Test value (random). Change it back according to your code later.
    var venta3 = Math.floor((Math.random() * 100)); // Test value (random). Change it back according to your code later.

    var vt0     = $('input[name="venta"]:eq(0)',this); // Set target input with their own index (eq).
    var vt1     = $('input[name="venta"]:eq(1)',this); // Set target input with their own index (eq).
    var vt2     = $('input[name="venta"]:eq(2)',this); // Set target input with their own index (eq).
    var vt3     = $('input[name="venta"]:eq(3)',this); // Set target input with their own index (eq).

    vt0.val(venta0).prop('checked',true) // Set the value
    .closest("label").html(function(){ // Customize/Set again the html in label. Because this input inside the label and its text value
        return [$("input",this),$("input",this).val()]; // Return the input in this label with its text value back into html
    });
    vt1.val(venta1) // Set the value
    .closest("label").html(function(){ // Customize/Set again the html in label. Because this input inside the label and its text value
        return [$("input",this),$("input",this).val()]; // Return the input in this label with its text value back into html
    });
    vt2.val(venta2) // Set the value
    .closest("label").html(function(){ // Customize/Set again the html in label. Because this input inside the label and its text value
        return [$("input",this),$("input",this).val()]; // Return the input in this label with its text value back into html
    });
    vt3.val(venta3) // Set the value
    .closest("label").html(function(){ // Customize/Set again the html in label. Because this input inside the label and its text value
        return [$("input",this),$("input",this).val()]; // Return the input in this label with its text value back into html
    });
});
```

JSFiddle example : http://jsfiddle.net/synz/72pasuzw/

Comment: Yes, that is what I am looking for!. But I don't know why the value is not showed in the modal (with your test value works). I thought is because the input when the page is load don't exist and because that the value is empty... but if I add something inside of val() the input change to NaN or object object

Comment: when I open the modal for the first time (https://imgur.com/9rZHYQ1) the value in each radio is empty, but when I close the modal and then opened again, the values are shown (https://imgur.com/3bRCGO9). Do you know why happens these?

Comment: Er-mm. I don't know why is that. It should be set the value already. I don't have the rest of your code. So I can't answer that. Do you do action(code) before open modal and set the value?

Comment: Yes, because if I don't choose the item the input button is not there, javascript create every line of input if the item exist. with you demo value, works in the first time, but with the my code since the second time...

Comment: update you question with the result of the table/HTML you got before you want do the action for clicking the modal button. I need to know where you got this val from `$('#venta_3'+id[1]).val(); and others` and what/where is the `id[1]` come from.

Comment: I already edit the post. Added a video and where the `id[1]` came

Answer (score 0):

Forgive me if I'm misunderstanding, but it looks like the problem is simply that you haven't added a `value` attribute to each of your radio buttons. I've added some samples here; you can run it and see if this is what you're missing.

```js
$('input').on('click', function(e) {
    alert($('#'+ e.target.id).val());
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="escoger" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog">

    <!-- Modal content-->
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">

        <label class="radio-inline mr10">
            <input type="radio" name="venta" id="venta_0" value="venta_0 value">1
        </label>
        <label class="radio-inline mr10">
            <input type="radio" name="venta" id="venta_1" value="venta_1 value">2
        </label>
        <label class="radio-inline mr10">
            <input type="radio" name="venta" id="venta_2" value="venta_2 value">3
        </label>
        <label class="radio-inline mr10">
            <input type="radio" name="venta" id="venta_3" value="venta_3 value">4
        </label>

      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: No, when I click over any of the input radio, the value is not the value from DB and  that is the issue I have...the values doesn't show in each input, like per example if the item  glue have  the info 3.10 , 2.45 , 2.10 and 1.90, those are the values I need to show in each radio button instead of 1 ,2 ,3 ,4. Then when I choose one of them, I need that the javascript change the value in the input